# How to reloads the table when clicked using AJAX in reactjs Put Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net

I was wondering how will I reload only the table, not the whole page on reacts. I've tried using `history.go(0);` however, it reloads the whole page please check how can I reload it, if I was going to use `forceUpdate`, based on research you should avoid using it. I'm trying do an AJAX but I don't know what to put where to put it... it is way different than PHP..

My code for the `onclick`:

```
handleUpdate(id, name, address,department){ 
   
    const data = {
      'Employee_ID': id,
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department
    }
    return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PutEmployeeDetail/'+id, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
     })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((result)=> {
      var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue]; 
      
      jsonReturnedValue[data].Department = department,
      jsonReturnedValue[data].Employee_name = name,
      jsonReturnedValue[data].Address = address
      this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);

    })
}
```

code for the render and the table:

```
render() {
     const isEnabled = this.canBeSubmitted();
    let {jsonReturnedValue} = this.state;
  return(
    <div>
        <div className="container">   
          <h1> Listof Employees </h1>
            <button className ='btn btn-warning right ' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddEmployee"> Add an Employee</button>
             <table className= "table table-bordered" id="result"> 
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Address</th>
                      <th>Update</th>
                      <th>Delete</th>
                 </tr>
                    {jsonReturnedValue.map((d,i) => this.renderItem(d,i))}
                </tbody>

            </table>
          </div>

      {/*Updating*/}

    <div className="modal fade" id="UpdateEmployee" role="dialog">
           <div className="modal-dialog">
             <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 className="modal-title">Update Employee</h4>
            </div>
            <form > 
              <div className="container"> 
              <div className="modal-body"> 
              <table> 
              <tbody> 
              <tr> 
              <td>Name</td> 
              <td> 
              <input  type="text" 
                      name="Employee_Name"
                      value={this.state.Employee_Name} 
                      required
                      onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Employee_Name")}/> 
              </td> 
              </tr> 
              <tr> 
              <td>Address</td> 
              <td> 
              <input  type="text" 
                      name="Address" 
                      value={this.state.Address} 
                      required
                      onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Address")}/> 
              </td> 
              </tr> 
              <tr> 
              <td>Department</td> 
              <td> 
              <input  type="text" 
                      name='Department' 
                      value={this.state.Department} 
                      required
                      onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, "Department")}/> 
              
              </td> 
              </tr> 
              </tbody> 
              </table> 
              </div> 
              </div> 
              <div className="modal-footer"> 
              <input type="button" className="btn btn-info"   disabled={!isEnabled}  onClick = { this.handleUpdate.bind(this,  this.state.Employee_ID , this.state.Employee_Name ,this.state.Address ,this.state.Department)} value =" Update Employee" data-dismiss="modal"/> 
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
              </div> 
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This appears to be the second of two duplicates of one of your previous questions, and as I have noted, you have duplicated your questions elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonReturnedValue` should use the `index` and not `object`. Make use of `findIndex` to get the index of the object with `Employee_ID = id` in the array

```
handleUpdate(id, name, address,department){ 

    const data = {
      'Employee_ID': id,
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department
    }
    return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PutEmployeeDetail/'+id, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
     })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((result)=> {
      var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue]; 
      var idx = jsonReturnedValue.findIndex((val) => val.Employee_ID == id)
      jsonReturnedValue[idx].Department = department,
      jsonReturnedValue[idx].Employee_name = name,
      jsonReturnedValue[idx].Address = address
      this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);

    })

}
```

Comment: when i debugged it the code is reading the values but its not changing the table unless i refresh it

Comment: If you setState, it should update the view

Comment: i did i dont know what happened ...

Comment: sometimes it updates sometimes it dont,,

Comment: It shouldn't be the case

Comment: and when i add and update the first i add it works but when i refresh it it didnt saved..